# Tunelling VNC through two ssh hops

Tags: ssh, firewall, portforwarding, tunneling

I've long seeked a solution to tunnel to a machine behind a firewall, passing VNC (or other ports) through. Like explained in this [old usenet post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.security.ssh/Q80te9jKAv4), which I'll recap here:

I have to log through an intermediate machine, something like:

```
local $ ssh interim
interim $ ssh remote
remote $ ...any commands...
```

This works fine. But now I am trying to tunnel a vnc session from remote to local and I can't find the magic incantation, using either one or two steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently found a wonderfully simple and adaptable solution: simply tunnel the ssh to the target system through the connection to the firewall. Like such:

```
local $ ssh -L 2222:remote:22 interim
interim $ ...no need to do anything here...
```

In another local console you connect to localhost on port 2222, which is actually your remote destination:

```
local $ ssh -C -p 2222 -L 5900:localhost:5900 localhost
remote $ ...possibly start you VNC server here...
```

In yet another local console:

```
local $ xtightvncviewer :0
```

It's that simple. You can add any port forwarding you want to the 2nd command (`-L localport:localhost:remoteport`) just like if there wasn't any intermediate firewall. For instance for RDP: `-L 3389:localhost:3389`

Comment: should do the trick: `ssh -C -J user@interim user@remote -L 5900:localhost:5900`